# timm: AssertionError: Batch size should be even when using this

Tags: python, torch, batchsize

I am implementing simple example for creating a model from scratch using timm. My batch is even but still i am getting an error and I am following below tutorials

https://gist.github.com/Chris-hughes10/a9e5ec2cd7e7736c651bf89b5484b4a9

```
import argparse
from pathlib import Path

import timm
import timm.data
import timm.loss
import timm.optim
import timm.utils
import torch
import torchmetrics
from timm.scheduler import CosineLRScheduler

from pytorch_accelerated.callbacks import SaveBestModelCallback
from pytorch_accelerated.trainer import Trainer, DEFAULT_CALLBACKS


def create_datasets(image_size, data_mean, data_std, train_path, val_path):
    train_transforms = timm.data.create_transform(
        input_size=image_size,
        is_training=True,
        mean=data_mean,
        std=data_std,
        auto_augment="rand-m7-mstd0.5-inc1",
    )

    eval_transforms = timm.data.create_transform(
        input_size=image_size, mean=data_mean, std=data_std
    )

    train_dataset = timm.data.dataset.ImageDataset(
        train_path, transform=train_transforms
    )
    eval_dataset = timm.data.dataset.ImageDataset(val_path, transform=eval_transforms)

    return train_dataset, eval_dataset


class TimmMixupTrainer(Trainer):
    def __init__(self, eval_loss_fn, mixup_args, num_classes, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.eval_loss_fn = eval_loss_fn
        self.num_updates = None
        self.mixup_fn = timm.data.Mixup(**mixup_args)

        self.accuracy = torchmetrics.Accuracy(num_classes=num_classes)
        self.ema_accuracy = torchmetrics.Accuracy(num_classes=num_classes)
        self.ema_model = None

    def create_scheduler(self):
        return timm.scheduler.CosineLRScheduler(
            self.optimizer,
            t_initial=self.run_config.num_epochs,
            cycle_decay=0.5,
            lr_min=1e-6,
            t_in_epochs=True,
            warmup_t=3,
            warmup_lr_init=1e-4,
            cycle_limit=1,
        )

    def training_run_start(self):
        # Model EMA requires the model without a DDP wrapper and before sync batchnorm conversion
        self.ema_model = timm.utils.ModelEmaV2(
            self._accelerator.unwrap_model(self.model), decay=0.9
        )
        if self.run_config.is_distributed:
            self.model = torch.nn.SyncBatchNorm.convert_sync_batchnorm(self.model)

    def train_epoch_start(self):
        super().train_epoch_start()
        self.num_updates = self.run_history.current_epoch * len(self._train_dataloader)

    def calculate_train_batch_loss(self, batch):
        xb, yb = batch
        mixup_xb, mixup_yb = self.mixup_fn(xb, yb)
        return super().calculate_train_batch_loss((mixup_xb, mixup_yb))

    def train_epoch_end(
            self,
    ):
        self.ema_model.update(self.model)
        self.ema_model.eval()

        if hasattr(self.optimizer, "sync_lookahead"):
            self.optimizer.sync_lookahead()

    def scheduler_step(self):
        self.num_updates += 1
        if self.scheduler is not None:
            self.scheduler.step_update(num_updates=self.num_updates)

    def calculate_eval_batch_loss(self, batch):
        with torch.no_grad():
            xb, yb = batch
            outputs = self.model(xb)
            val_loss = self.eval_loss_fn(outputs, yb)
            self.accuracy.update(outputs.argmax(-1), yb)

            ema_model_preds = self.ema_model.module(xb).argmax(-1)
            self.ema_accuracy.update(ema_model_preds, yb)

        return {"loss": val_loss, "model_outputs": outputs, "batch_size": xb.size(0)}

    def eval_epoch_end(self):
        super().eval_epoch_end()

        if self.scheduler is not None:
            self.scheduler.step(self.run_history.current_epoch + 1)

        self.run_history.update_metric("accuracy", self.accuracy.compute().cpu())
        self.run_history.update_metric(
            "ema_model_accuracy", self.ema_accuracy.compute().cpu()
        )
        self.accuracy.reset()
        self.ema_accuracy.reset()


def main(data_path):
    # Set training arguments, hardcoded here for clarity
    image_size = (224, 224)
    lr = 5e-3
    smoothing = 0.1
    mixup = 0.2
    cutmix = 1.0
    batch_size = 32
    bce_target_thresh = 0.2
    num_epochs = 40

    data_path = Path(data_path)
    train_path = data_path / "train"
    val_path = data_path / "val"
    num_classes = len(list(train_path.iterdir()))

    mixup_args = dict(
        mixup_alpha=mixup,
        cutmix_alpha=cutmix,
        label_smoothing=smoothing,
        num_classes=num_classes,
    )

    # Create model using timm
    model = timm.create_model(
        "resnet50d", pretrained=False, num_classes=num_classes, drop_path_rate=0.05
    )

    # Load data config associated with the model to use in data augmentation pipeline
    data_config = timm.data.resolve_data_config({}, model=model, verbose=True)
    data_mean = data_config["mean"]
    data_std = data_config["std"]

    # Create training and validation datasets
    train_dataset, eval_dataset = create_datasets(
        train_path=train_path,
        val_path=val_path,
        image_size=image_size,
        data_mean=data_mean,
        data_std=data_std,
    )

    # Create optimizer
    optimizer = timm.optim.create_optimizer_v2(
        model, opt="lookahead_AdamW", lr=lr, weight_decay=0.01
    )

    # As we are using Mixup, we can use BCE during training and CE for evaluation
    train_loss_fn = timm.loss.BinaryCrossEntropy(
        target_threshold=bce_target_thresh, smoothing=smoothing
    )
    validate_loss_fn = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

    # Create trainer and start training
    trainer = TimmMixupTrainer(
        model=model,
        optimizer=optimizer,
        loss_func=train_loss_fn,
        eval_loss_fn=validate_loss_fn,
        mixup_args=mixup_args,
        num_classes=num_classes,
        callbacks=[
            *DEFAULT_CALLBACKS,
            SaveBestModelCallback(watch_metric="accuracy", greater_is_better=True),
        ],
    )

    trainer.train(
        per_device_batch_size=batch_size,
        train_dataset=train_dataset,
        eval_dataset=eval_dataset,
        num_epochs=num_epochs,
        create_scheduler_fn=trainer.create_scheduler,
    )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Simple example of training script using timm.")
    parser.add_argument("--data_dir", required=True, help="The data folder on disk.")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    main(args.data_dir)
```

**Traceback**

```
100%|█████████▉| 333/334 [00:37<00:00,  9.09it/s]Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cvpr/PycharmProjects/timm_tutorials/scratch_model.py", line 201, in <module>
    main(args.data_dir)
  File "/home/cvpr/PycharmProjects/timm_tutorials/scratch_model.py", line 188, in main
    trainer.train(
  File "/home/cvpr/anaconda3/envs/timm_tutorials/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_accelerated/trainer.py", line 437, in train
    self._run_training()
  File "/home/cvpr/anaconda3/envs/timm_tutorials/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_accelerated/trainer.py", line 641, in _run_training
    self._run_train_epoch(self._train_dataloader)
  File "/home/cvpr/anaconda3/envs/timm_tutorials/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_accelerated/trainer.py", line 704, in _run_train_epoch
    batch_output = self.calculate_train_batch_loss(batch)
  File "/home/cvpr/PycharmProjects/timm_tutorials/scratch_model.py", line 78, in calculate_train_batch_loss
    mixup_xb, mixup_yb = self.mixup_fn(xb, yb)
  File "/home/cvpr/anaconda3/envs/timm_tutorials/lib/python3.8/site-packages/timm/data/mixup.py", line 210, in __call__
    assert len(x) % 2 == 0, 'Batch size should be even when using this'
AssertionError: Batch size should be even when using this
100%|█████████▉| 333/334 [00:37<00:00,  8.93it/s]
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see the model works perfectly until the last batch of the epoch. It is because for the final batch, the loader get the remaining images and put them together in this batch. Unfortunately this final batch seems to have odd size.

Comment: Yes, the last batch size is odd but what is the solution of this problem?